# jQuery UI menu loses focus when any item is selected

Tags: jquery-ui, menu

I've created a simple Jquery menu but have run into a problem I cannot isolate:

**The first item I mouseover is fine, but as soon as I move to another item (parent and child items alike) the menu loses focus.**

What I've done to try and isolate the problem:

- removed all CSS from my page
- using base theme for Jquery UI **1.10.3**
- removed all other javascript from the page
- using Jquery **1.7.2**
- Tried debugging, I get no errors
- Code works in fiddle
- Included **menu.js, widget.js, ui.js, position.js and core.js** in the `<head>`

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
 <form>
  <div style="width:50%">
  <ul id="buildingmenu">
   <li><a href="#">Social Update</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Building Update</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">building 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">building 2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </form>
</body>
```

And my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buildingmenu").menu();
});
```

I'm pulling out my hair, what have I missed??

**EDIT:** Here's a [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3J4_uskZdQ) of the problem with chrome inspector open

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/B2HFE/ in what browser are you testing it?

Comment: I've tested in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. And it works fine in jsfiddle for me as well. This is why I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Try including position too, is a required dependence for menu, added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With full jQuery UI version included works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/B2HFE/

Reading the [`docs`](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/) I see the dependecies of jQuery UI menu are:

- UI Core
- Widget Factory
- [Position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)

I think you miss the last one.

Comment: I forgot to add position.js to my post. I've included it as well.

Comment: Another clue: The menu loses focus on parent items that don't have a child menu. So if I mouseover a regular item it has focus for a second, then loses it. Consistently.

Comment: In a similar sample code in you local do you have the problem? I prepare a fiddle with that dependecies included in a few. Do you include FULL core, widget and position js right?

Comment: Yes my code is almost verbatim. I am using the same dependencies

Comment: It works with partial jQuery UI too: http://jsfiddle.net/B2HFE/1/, have you setTimeout or other functions?

Comment: No, there is nothing else running on the page. Here is the source code after page load. http://pastebin.com/5CMvMnd7

I don't know if it's relevant but I am running this on Sitecore with ASP.NET -- the page is loaded as an .ascx and the menu is inside a user control

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30428/discussion-between-matt-foxx-duncan-and-edward)

Comment: What about css are they splitted too; can you provide them on pastedin or try including the full?

Comment: The css used is at the top of the pastebin link I posted earlier. They are all unmodified and from the default jquery ui package

Comment: Please post the content of all css included too so I can try with your case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30435/discussion-between-matt-foxx-duncan-and-edward)

Comment: Nope, I gave up trying to figure it out. It was taking too much time. I ended up create a psuedo-menu with jquery selectable that did the job.
  
  
However I'll mark it solved as I'm sure any of your answers would have worked in a normal situation. Thanks for the help